# Redirect Non-WWW to WWW URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

When people access my domain it is redirected to
http://www.mydomain.com/en/index.php using php code.I added the following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RedirectPermanent /pages/abc-123.html http://www.mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php
```

to redirect people from **non www to www**,

Still users can access by typing both http://mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php and http://www.mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php  URLs

Does anyone know the method to completely redirect to http://www.mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php  even if user typed http://www.mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php, and prohibit accessing URLs  without www.

Comment: The idea of that rewrite is to redirect user to www if he comes to non-www. So non-www is still accessible, but tells browser to redirect to www and keep that url in the cache, as this is permanent (301) redirect. So, from user's point of view, when he is accessing `domain.com`, browser automatically redirects to `www.domain.com`. Do your users see `domain.com` in browser's address bar?

Comment: No, user wont see domain.com, but he can open  http://mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php page in the browser.

Comment: And what do you want to do? Prohibit the user typing that URL in browser?:) If you want to deny `domain.com` service at all, just redirect it to `404` page, with something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]`

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042309/www-and-non-www-sites, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685962/htaccess-redirect-non-www-to-www-preserving-uri-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707319/non-www-to-www-htaccess-redirect, etc

Answer (score 13):

```
$protocol = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";

if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
    header('Location: '.$protocol.'www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```

in php

Comment: `strncmp($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www.', 4) === 0` ;)

Comment: What happens if I access `sub.mydomain.com`?

Comment: The slash is not necessary "/". It make unwanted additional slash on the redirect. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$protocol = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
    header('Location: '.$protocol.'www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Working Properly

Comment: While this is an answer, could you expand on it at all? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how to do it through .htaccess, but I do it with PHP code myself within my `config.php` which is loaded for every file.

```
if(substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],0,4) != "www." && $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != 'localhost')
    header('Location: http://www.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

**EDIT:** @genesis, you are correct I forgot about https

Change

```
header('Location: http://www.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

to

```
header('Location: '.
       (@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://').
       'www.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: You should use HTTP_HOST instead of SERVER_NAME; (and strncmp() instead of substr() ;) )

Comment: I used HTTP_HOST before, I switched to SERVER_NAME because it includes the final `/`. Why should I use HTTP_HOST instead?

Comment: HTTP_HOST is the Host header sent by the client; I believe SERVER_NAME is based the `ServerName` directive of the VirtualHost (and does is not necessarily the real hostname of the url)

Answer (score 2):

Add `RewriteEngine On` before `RewriteCond` to enable your rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And if you have https:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .? - [E=PROTO:http]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .? - [E=PROTO:https]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %{ENV:PROTO}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi arnaud576875, i had added RewriteEngine On, but still doesnt work.

Comment: make sure that .htaccess are enabled in your server

Comment: .htaccess is enabled, since along with the above mentioned code there are few RedirectPermanent,redirect 301 codes which works fine.

Comment: and it doesn't redirects at all ?

Comment: It works, and redirect to other pages, but only this Non-WWW to WWW URLs is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 /pages/abc-123.html http://www.mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you have other rules in your `.htaccess` file you should update your question to add them so we can advice where to place the code.

Comment: Hi shef,along with the above mentioned code there is few RedirectPermanent,redirect 301 code also there.

Comment: @Ullas Prabhakar: If you are using `redirect 301 ...` sytanx, than it should be outside the `IfModule`, otherwise you should edit your question to add all the code so I can suggest where to place the above code for it to work.

Comment: @Ullas Prabhakar: I have updated the code, make sure to change `mydomain` with your actual domain name. Just drop it all in the `.htaccess` file and it should work flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but even the code you suggested is also not working, though the redirect 301 is working

Comment: @Ullas Prabhakar: How are you testing it? Are you trying to visit `http://mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php` and it is not redirecting you to `http://www.mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php`?

Comment: Yes, i tried opening both URL's  mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php and   www.mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php,Unfortunately both are working.The URL without www is not redirecting to URL with www.

Comment: @Ullas Prabhakar: That's the code to redirect non-www to www, there is no doubt about that, because I am using it in production servers. The last question to be asked: do you have the module `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite is enabled, since `Redirect 301 /pages/abc-123.html http://www.mydomain.com/en/page-a1/abc.php` is working, but this Non-WWW to WWW is the only thing not working.Do you know any other method to do this??

Comment: @Ullas Prabhakar: `Redirect 301 ...` does not require `mod_rewrite` it requires `mod_alias`. Please check if you have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Comment: :Yes,mod_rewrite is enabled. I checked using the methods mentioned in this two links [www.workingwith.me.uk](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) and [www.webune.com](http://www.webune.com/forums/how-to-test-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-t40.html), which are working

Comment: @Ullas Prabhakar: I don't know what you are doing wrong, but I am 100% sure that the above code works, because, as I said, I am using it in my production servers.

Comment: I had tried your code and the code i had mentioned,dont know why RewriteRule is not working but rest of the codes are working like redirect 301, Redirectpermanent.I have checked in phpinfo, both mod_alias & mod_rewrite are enabled.Can you suggest any other way or anything else do i need to check to rectify this issue.

Comment: @Ullas Prabhakar: Can we access your site somewhere? Or are you working in a local machine?

Comment: @Ullas Prabhakar: Where have you placed the `.htaccess` file? It must be above `/en/`, that is, it must be on root in order for it to work.

Comment: :Yes,Shef I placed it in the root.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to redirect the user instead of rewriting the URL, in that case use `Redirect` or 'RedirectMatch` directive. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new-extern