# Redirect https:// to https://www on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect

I'd like to redirect `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` for my PHP project on Google App Engine.

**What I've done so far:**

1. Added and mapped the custom domains for both `example.com` and `www.example.com`.
2. Updated the DNS with the provided records to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`.
3. Uploaded an SSL that covers both `example.com` and `www.example.com`.
4. Added "secure: always" in the app.yaml.

**Here's what happens:**

1. `http://example.com` redirects to `https://example.com`.
2. `http://www.example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com`.

The website resolves properly for both URLs, but I'd prefer that the secure naked domain redirects to the secure www subdomain. I've researched all of the related posts on Stack Overflow, but can't seem to find anyone having the same issue.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you do that at the app level? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228653/redirect-non-www-to-www-urls

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a try, then post my result.  I'm new to web development, so there are a few things I still don't understand yet.  But I'll try my best to figure it out.

Comment: The recommendation to redirect `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` is to do so in the application or use a third-party DNS platform.

Comment: @zengr: because App Engine does not use apache and thus does not use `.htaccess` files.