# htaccess - get all non-www traffic redirected to the www

Tags: .htaccess, no-www

Can anyone suggest how I get non www traffic to redirect to the www version of a website using the htaccess file - I know I have one created in my root directory but cannot be sure what to put.. any ideas

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-www to www htaccess redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707319/non-www-to-www-htaccess-redirect)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Relatively easily.

Match anything that does not begin with 'www.' and then redirect to the 'www.' version:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```