# Redirect non www domain to a www domain without affecting subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

@Starkeen, this code didn't work for me. All other pages now have 404 errors and homepage didn't get the www added.

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314520/htaccess-get-all-non-www-traffic-redirected-to-the-www

Comment: @Starkeen, this is what I have. It seems a bit long right?

Comment: @Starkeen saved it but the www didn't get added and all other pages get the 404 error, help buddy! many thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this  to your htaccess file right after the "RewriteEngine on" directive

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [NC,R=301]
```

**Edit**

Added the missing **L** flag to first Rewrite

Try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks @Starkeen, do I need to have a space between your code and that directive? Should I remove the RewriteCond/RewriteRule from the bottom as well?

Comment: the homepage works without www added and all other pages have gone offline

Comment: Zwan , sorry there was a typo, I edited my answer, Reload the page to see it.

Comment: homepage is online but still no www and all other pages are getting the 404 error. Here is a link to the site: http://bit.ly/1CZqrN2

Comment: Clear your browser's cache and try

Comment: cleared cache and still not working, please see site.

Comment: Frank, the code is working fine on my apache server, non www to www is redirecting successfully, and  path that is not related to existing files and dir is redirecting to **index.php** .

Comment: why is not working on my server? All other pages are 404 errors

Comment: is htaccess enabled on your server?

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it worked, you may accept this answer if it worked.